# Matlab adjusting heat map axes and colors

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create a heat map which is something I'm not very familiar with. I have a large matrix of the form:

```
One=
[0 2 4 6 8
 2 1 3 5 6
 4 5 8 3 1
 6 2 7 4 8
 8 3 9 5 4]
```

And I want to create a heat map such that the topmost row and the leftmost column are the axes.
So far I've managed this:

```
figure(1)
Plot = One;     
colormap('hot');   
imagesc(Plot);
```

I've also noticed that in the 'hot' colormap, the small numbers are very dark and the large numbers are white. Is there a way to reverse that?

Comment: `colormap(flipud(hot))`. You may also want to add a `colorbar`

Comment: for the Axis you could just index your matrix, something like data = One(2:end,2:end); and define your two axis and then plot with those axis values.

Comment: @Luis Mendo, you should write it as an answer, even though its a short one, it still is the best answer imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a good start:

```
One = ...
[0 2 4 6 8
 2 1 3 5 6
 4 5 8 3 1
 6 2 7 4 8
 8 3 9 5 4];

figure();
imagesc(One(1,:), One(:,1), One(2:end,2:end));
get(gca(), 'ydir', 'normal')
colormap(flipud(hot()));
colorbar();
```

[image]

Notice that the x & y axis are larger than the data, so perhaps one needs to exclude `One(1,1)`:

```
figure();
imagesc(One(1,2:end), One(2:end,1), One(2:end,2:end));
get(gca(), 'ydir', 'normal')
colormap(flipud(hot()));
colorbar();
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Generate the colormap with the [`hot`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) function and flip it upside down with [`flipud`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html):

```
colormap(flipud(hot))
```

By default this produces 64 colors. If you want to specify a different number, say 128, use

```
colormap(flipud(hot(128)))
```